# Can't create user in mesibo using android app

Tags: android, mesibo

I want to create user at Mesibo but i am facing some issues :

Sorry, we can't find that page It seems the page you’re looking for doesn’t exist. Maybe you’re on the wrong track, maybe you found a broken link. Who knows?

Please anyone here to help related to these issues and also help to complete my this task and I am using following URL for creating a user at "Mesibo".
"https://mesibo.com/api/api.php?token=cn9cvk6gnm15e7lrjb2k7ggggax5h90n5x7dp4sam6kwitl2hmg4cmwabet4zgdw&op=useradd&appid=com.mesibo.demoapp&addr=18005550001"

token = Application Token
appid = Android or iOS app id (for example, com.mesibo.xxx). In case of web, just pass, ‘web’ as appid. Note that, for security reasons, the token generated for a particular appid will only be usable on app matching that appid.
addr = end point address, for example, a user phone number.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of** "https://mesibo.com/api/api.php?..." **use** "**https://api.mesibo.com/api.php?token=...**"